# Bigquery - Create external tables using a query

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I have a complex query which has multiple joins and aggregations. The output of the data is in billions now. Looking for a best approach to have this output data into an external table

I was able to do the following things (both were done using python)
-Export the query output into an Internal table
-Export Internal table into GCS

I had to combine the above steps and then create an external table on top of it. Is there any other efficient way to create an external table based on the query output directly?

Comment: I think your solution is the best: Write the result into a new BigQuery table by using `create table dataset.name as Select ... ` and then export this table to GCS. The drawback is that in the GCS the table is splitted into many files, which you need to combine manually again. The BigQuery output is too large to load it in a python pandas dataset. In case you want to load the external table back into a database, please consider using a REST or ODBC access to Bigquery.

Comment: Hi @Sri Bharath, did the above comment help?

Comment: Hi @ShipraSarkar - Yes that was already implemented. But not for huge datasets. We had to use Dataflow to export the BigQuery data into Parquet on GCS for larger datasets

Comment: Hi @SriBharath. can you clarify your requirements by providing more details?